# Aggregation "items" does not exist in Element sap.m.StandardListItem#subcatId

Tags: javascript, odata, expand, sapui5

Im trying to bind products of certain categories, in each category there is an expand of products, first of all i list the categories from default oData service read-write only `http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc`, then by clicking the one of category im taking its path( it returns like: `Category(1)` or `Category(2)` and etc ), and use it to call the products of this category, but there is a mistake, **Aggregation "items" does not exist in Element sap.m.StandardListItem#subcatId** what im doing wrong?

here is the code that take the sPath of category then trying to retrieve the list of products of this category:

```
    var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("appId");
    var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("listId");

    var sItem = list.getSelectedItem();
    var sPath = sItem.oBindingContexts.data.sPath;

    var sCont = sap.ui.getCore().byId("subcatId");
    var sCats = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        parameters: {expand: "Products"},
        title: "{data>Name}"
    })

    sCont.bindAggregation("items","data>"+sPath,sCats);
```

the api's:

`http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Categories`
`http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products`
`http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$expand=Products`

thank you all for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that sCont is an instance of [sap.m.StandardListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardListItem.html). The StandardListItem does not have an aggregation "items" as you can see from the API docs. Instead of calling

```
sCont.bindAggregation("items","data>"+sPath,sCats);
```

you should try to bind the items aggregation of the corresponding list like this:

```
list.bindAggregation("items",...);
```

I can see in your code snippet that you even retrieved the list in the second line:

```
var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("listId");
```

Comment: im just a beginner :) need to read more documentation )) thank you for help!

Comment: oh, never mind - I'm happy you are trying to learn UI5 ;-) I suggest to start with the walkthrough tutorial which you find in the tutorials section at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com. Maybe you would like to read my tutorials as well: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/